# Generating function value within variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to use the Random function within the variable in `Jmeter` for example
`${demo_variable_g${__Random(1,4,)}}`

I am extracting the values for `demo_variable` using regular expression extractor. I want to generate random number while using the extracted variable value. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The correct function would be:

```
${__V(demo_variable_g${__Random(1,4,)})}
```

From the [__V() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)

> For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:
>
> - **${A1}** - works OK
> - **${A${N}}** - does not work (nested variable reference)
> - **${__V(A${N})}** - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for explanation and demos